# Is there a defined method for storing Adobe XMP in HTML?

Tags: html, xmp

Adobe has defined standard methods for storing XMP metadata inside of a variety of file formats including PDF, TIFF, JPEG, GIF, SWF, MP3, MP4, etc. However, I can't find any documentation defining a standardized method for storing XMP in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Note I'm note into `XMP`but I found this in the specification of adobe, maybe it helps:

All quoted from the [XMP Specification Part 3](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart3.pdf) (page 41ff):

**2.5.1 HTML**

`XMP` embedded in `HTML` should conform to one of the W3C recommendations for embedding `XML` in `HTML`.
For reference information, see the meeting report for the May 1998 W3C meeting: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-xh

`XML` can be embedded in a `SCRIPT` or `XML` element, placed in any legal location; the suggested location is the end of the `HEAD` element. The content of the `SCRIPT` or `XML` element is the `XMP` packet. The browser must recognize the `SCRIPT` or `XML` element so that text representing the value of RDF properties is not displayed as page content. Using the `XML` element is preferred unless there are known incompatibilities with older software; if so, the `SCRIPT` element is likely to be recognized.

**2.5.1.1 Embedding `XML` in `HTML`**

There are three approaches to embedding `XML` in `HTML`, as shown in the examples below. Two use the `SCRIPT` element, and the third uses the `XML` element.

**2.5.1.1.1 Using the `SCRIPT` element and `LANGUAGE` attribute**

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="XML">
        <?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
        <!-- The serialized RDF goes here. It is removed for brevity. -->
        <?xpacket end='w'?>
      </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**NOTE**: Adobe has noticed problems with using the `SCRIPT` element and `LANGUAGE` attribute in Microsoft Word 2000 running under Microsoft Windows XP: the body content cannot be displayed

**2.5.1.1.2 Using the `SCRIPT` element and `TYPE` attribute**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/xml">
      <?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
      <!-- The serialized RDF goes here. It is removed for brevity. -->
      <?xpacket end='w'?>
    </SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2.5.1.1.3 Using the `XML` element**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <XML>
      <?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
      <!-- The serialized RDF goes here. It is removed for brevity. -->
      <?xpacket end='w'?>
    </XML>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```